# New C++11 for loop causes "error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope" using it for an struct with array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, struct

I'm having a struct with an array which is static and want to access the data in that array. Tried to use the new C++11 for loops and also do it without the for loop and just print `array[1]`. See the second `cout` in the main function.

I already know that the problem have to do something with the fact that the array in the struct `tCalcAngularEstimationFromComplexData_32` is adjusted as a pointer type. Therefore I tried to use `for (const auto &arr : &test_data_1)` but wasn't able to solve it.
Thanks.

```
typedef struct tComplex_R {
    float real;
    float imag;
}tComplex_R;

typedef struct tOutputVRx_R {
    float range;
    float vel;
    tComplex_R AmpLinRx[1];
} tOutputVRx_R;

typedef struct tCalcAngularEstimationFromComplexData_32{
  int antennas_azimuth;
  int antennas_elevation;
  tOutputVRx_R dataset1[32]; //Range Velocity and Complex Data for 32 Antennas
} tCalcAngularEstimationFromComplexData_32;

static tCalcAngularEstimationFromComplexData_32 tCalcAngEstComplexData_dataset_1 = {
       5, 90, 
       {{1, 3, {10, 15}}, 
        {2, 4, {11, 16}}       
       }         
};


int main(){

tCalcAngularEstimationFromComplexData_32 test_data_1 = tCalcAngEstComplexData_dataset_1;

cout << "Range 1: " << test_data_1.dataset1->range << endl;
cout << "Range 2: " << test_data_1.dataset1[1]->range << endl; //Not working

for (const auto &arr : test_data_1) {
    cout << "Range: " << arr.dataset1->range << endl;


   }
}
```

Comment: The thing after `:` has to be a list of things. `test_data_1` isn't a list, it's a single struct. You rpobably wanted `const auto &x : test_data_1.dataset1`, then print `x.range`?

Comment: Unrelated: `typedef`ining your `struct`s isn't necessary. They are typedefined automatically.

Comment: You need to add `begin()` and `end()` member functions to `tCalcAngularEstimationFromComplexData_32` if you want to use range based for-loops on instances of it. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/63TMGcbsv)

Comment: Thanks to to you all.

How can I access the data without using the for loop. See line `cout << "Range 2: " << test_data_1.dataset1[1]->range << endl; //Not working`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Range-based for loops need to have access to the bounds of what you're iterating.

As noted on [the relevant cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), there are three ways:

1. It is an array of known size (which is the case for your `dataset1` member)
2. `my_struct::begin()` and `my_struct::end()` are defined
3. `begin(my_struct&)` and `end(my_struct&)` are defined

As for this line:

```cpp
cout << "Range 2: " << test_data_1.dataset1[1]->range << endl; //Not working
```

It is because `dataset1[1]` is not a pointer but a reference, so you don't use `->` but `.` instead.

[See a working example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4M1sE8bdP)